# What is an alternative of push kit to do processing on killed state when notification is received for IOS 13 SDK

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios13, pushkit

On IOS13 push kit cannot be used other than callKit. I want to do processing on killed state just like WhatsApp and keep my application up-to date for good user experience. What could be the solution for doing processing on killed state.

To accomplish this I tried UserNotification framework but it doesn't allow to run custom code on killed state. Lower than IOS 13 push kit works fine but on IOS 13 it's not working.

Application should be able to do any operation on killed state just like WhatsApp to keep application data up-to date. For IOS 13 when received pushKit notification app got crashed on killed state.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try UNNotificationServiceExtension?
You can earn like 30 seconds execution time on a remote notification, as long as:

1. The remote notification is configured to display an alert.
2. The remote notification’s aps dictionary includes the mutable-content key with the value set to 1.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension?language=objc